# How to find out Number of Workdays between two dates in HANA?

Tags: date, hana

How to find out Number of Workdays (Monday to Friday) between two dates in SAP HANA ? We do not have to consider holidays.

We can't use `WORKDAYS_BETWEEN()` as we do not have `TFACS` table.

Comment: Could you please be more clear about your question. Where do you want to do this?
In XSJS or modelling?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can so ist in sql:

1. Calculate the number of whole weeks, multiply by 5
2. Add the remaining days: subtract weekday start date from weekday end date, correct for weekends (least...), Correct for carry-over (+5)

The second part can be simplified a little so that you don't have to write the subtraction twice.

Here an example with start date '2015-12-04' and end date '2015-12-19):

```
SELECT ROUND( DAYS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE ('2015-12-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2015-12-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) / 7, 0, ROUND_DOWN) * 5
                       + ( case
                             when WEEKDAY (TO_DATE('2015-12-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) - WEEKDAY (TO_DATE('2015-12-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) >= 0
                               then least( WEEKDAY (TO_DATE('2015-12-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD')), 5) - least( WEEKDAY (TO_DATE('2015-12-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD')), 5)
                             else
                                   least( WEEKDAY (TO_DATE('2015-12-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD')), 5) - least( WEEKDAY (TO_DATE('2015-12-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD')), 5) + 5
                          end )

           "Workdays" FROM DUMMY;
```

--> 11

Answer (score 0):

I preferred to create a user defined function here to use in HANA SQLScript codes as follows

```
Create Function CalculateWorkDays (startdate date, enddate date)
returns cnt integer
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT AS
begin
    declare i int;
    cnt := 0;
    i := 0;
    while :i <= days_between(:startdate, :enddate)
    do
        if WEEKDAY( ADD_DAYS(:startdate,:i) ) < 5
        then
            cnt := :cnt + 1;
        end if;
        i := :i + 1;
    end while;
end;
```

Please note that the above code block seems to contain an unnecessary loop.
On the other hand, if you have additional tables like department holidays, or personal holidays, etc. It might be useful to check these tables in the WHILE loop. Please refer to following SQL tutorial [Calculate the Count of Working Days Between Two Dates](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-function-to-count-work-days-between-two-dates.aspx) where I created a similar SQL function checking custom work calendars or holiday calendars.

Here is how you call the function as sample

```
select CalculateWorkDays('20170101', '20170131') as i from dummy;
```

I hope it helps,